# Negative string index vs. result of unsuccessful `find`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python,and I am confused about how the index of an array woks in python.
 Following is my code

```
test_var = "hello how are you"

print(test_var[-1], ",", test_var.find('t'))
```

The output of this program is.

> u , -1

Now I understand that negative indexing is allowed in python unlike java and it most probably works in cyclic manner so that `-1` indicates the last character.

But when it comes to `find` method and it does not match any character `'t'` it again gives `-1`. So does it imply that `-1` is like the null value in python?
And it does *not* mean that `find` has returned the position of the last character?

**Is it just me or would it be less confusing if an unsuccessful `find` would return `None`?**

Comment: The `-1` returned from `find` versus the `-1` used in indexing have completely different meanings (or semantics, you might say). The former means "item x wasn't found", the latter means "the last item in the list". These definitions are supposedly well-defined in Python documentation. If an item was found in a list, `find` will return a positive integer. Guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

For this example, if you index some element for an iterable (list, tuple, set or string) with negative integers, the elements start from the right to left with -1, something like this:

```
  0    1    2    3  
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  -4  -3   -2   -1
```

For the `find` function, this return -1 when it doesn't find an element, else return the index

Comment: In your example -1 -> d , so if find returns -1 should i not mean it is returning position of d ?

Comment: I was referring to the `find` of your example, if I write `list.find('d')` in the list of my example, it return 3

Comment: yes exactly so [-1] is u but while returning index it is 3

Comment: `find` function return positive index, work with it...if it return -1, is because it didn't find an element